# Why I am getting this exception when logging in to my own local Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I set up a Spigot server on my PC, created from the latest BuildTools. There are no errors on startup, but I can't log in due to a Java security exception.

I've tried updating Java to the latest release, creating a clean server directory, running both CraftBukkit and Spigot builds, with the matching version of Minecraft. I've connected to both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`, with and without specifying the port. In all cases the error is the same. This only happens with my local server- I'm able to log in to multiple remote servers just fine.

Client message:

`Failed to connect to the server
Disconnected`

Console message:

`[11:20:38 WARN]: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA
[11:20:38 WARN]:        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
...
[11:20:38 INFO]: com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile@479afd0d[id=<null>,name=WildWeazel,properties={},legacy=false] (/127.0.0.1:51608) lost connection: Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: `I've tried updating Java to the latest release` JDK 8u74

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using:

```
 -Djava.ext.dirs=../lib
```

as a startup directive for your java.
Try using a regular startup directive such as

```
java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar (jarfile)
```

If this does not work, you can try downgrading to Java 7

Comment: I don't recall what that was doing in the launch script, but sure enough that did it.

Comment: No problem, the ext.dir./lib directive is hardcoded and is not supported anymore, it was used back when Minecraft was in 1.3